# Cant Resolve Sysmbol SearchView and Unused android.support.v7.widget.SearchView

Tags: android

Fresh Meat on Android Studio.....

these few days i was try to develop a searchbar on appbar and i did google a lot of sample from user and developer but i fail to work it out.

website like
http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html and etc
but the last sample/tutorial i on is http://javarticles.com/2015/07/android-search-widget-example.html

after few try from few different website, i end-up at the same error which is
my SearchView having error, please refer to my screen capture below
[image]

Did i miss anything? or is my poor understanding on English....

my code is nothing special, i using the Android Studio new "Navigation Drawer Project" and try to follow(adding in code) from the website.

By the way i using ver23.1.1 now.

Thanks first for you help.

Comment: OMG! thanks George, i put it under public class then error disable, and both problem solve. ok lets continue the tutorial ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to first declare and initialize your `SearchView` before using it.

Try something like:

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
```

Replace `R.id.search` with the correct id from your `search_menu` file.